# Magestore checkout page show error in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am using latest Rewardspoint module for magento2 and it display me blank checkout page. When I checked the system.log then it show me this error;

> [2018-10-12 04:06:11] main.CRITICAL: Source class "\Magestore\Rewardpoints\Model\Plugin\Quote\Cart\CartTotalInterface" for "Magestore\Rewardpoints\Model\Plugin\Quote\Cart\CartTotalRepository" generation does not exist. [] []

Both of the above directories do not exist in rewardspoint module.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem. MagePlaza Core module was not compatible to latest RewardsPoints module.
After upgrading MagePlaza Core module, problem resolved.
https://github.com/mageplaza/module-core

Answer (score 0):

Can try to run the following script first to see to problem solve or not.

If the problem still exist, i will update the answer.

```
rm -rf var/di
rm -rf var/cache
rm -rf var/generation
rm -rf var/page_cache

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I already flush the cache etc with these mentioned commands still no luck